# How to change the opacity of PSTricks strokes?

Tags: pstricks

I need to change the opacity of PSTricks strokes, is it possible to do this?

Comment: This is the best forum ever :)

Comment: What does latex say when you try


    `\begin{pspicture}[linewidth=1cm](4,4)
      \psline[linecolor=yellow,strokeopacity=0.5](0,0.5) (4,0.5)
    \end{pspicture}`

Please give us the complete log and describe your observation.

Comment: @Eric: Congratulation, you solved the problem. I have `strokeopacity` today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What does **latex** say when you try

```
\begin{pspicture}[linewidth=1cm](4,4)
   \psline[linecolor=yellow,strokeopacity=0.5](0,0.5) (4,0.5)
\end{pspicture}
```

Please give us the complete log and describe your observation.

Comment: `latex` said "thank you Eric!"