# Can you change the opacity in surfaces/plots in PSTricks pst-3dplot?

Tags: pstricks, pst-3dplot

Can you change the opacity in surfaces/plots in PSTricks pst-3dplot ?

```
\documentclass[%
  pstricks,%
  border=12pt%
]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-1.5)(3,4)
\pstThreeDCoor[%
  xMin=-4,%
  xMax=4,%
  yMin=-4,%
  yMax=4,%
  zMax=3,%
  arrows=<->%
]
\psplotThreeD[%
  plotstyle=line,%
  linecolor=blue,%
  yPlotpoints=40,%
  xPlotpoints=30,%
  linewidth=0.5pt,%
  hiddenLine=true%
](-2,2)(-2,2)
{
  x 100 mul cos y 100 mul sin sub
}
\rput[tl](-2,3.5){$f(x,y) = \cos(100x) - \sin(100y)$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The closest duplicate is [How to change stroke opacity](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37991/19356).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several tricks for effecting the opacity in `pstricks`, in this context what you want to use is `strokeopacity`.  So try:

```
\psplotThreeD[%
  strokeopacity=0.2,
  plotstyle=line,%
  linecolor=blue,%
  yPlotpoints=40,%
  xPlotpoints=30,%
  linewidth=0.5pt,%
  hiddenLine=true%
](-2,2)(-2,2)
{
  x 100 mul cos y 100 mul sin sub
}
```

[image]

If you're *filling* a figure, then simply using the key `opacity` should work.

```
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,4)
    \psset{fillstyle=solid}
    \pscircle[fillcolor=blue](0,0){2}
    \psellipse[fillcolor=yellow,opacity=0.75](1,2)(1,2)
\end{pspicture}
```

[image]

Comment: 7 seconds too slow